# Firefox absolute position different then Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, position

I have been encountering an error lately with some code. Basically, the absolute position property works correctly on Chrome but gives different results on Firefox. Any ideas why?

Representations:

Chrome:
[image: Correct]

Firefox:
[image: Incorrect]
NOTE: On the firefox representation the second small box exists but is cut off.

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="card-info">
        </div>
        <div class="arrow-wrapper">
            <i class=" visible-lg arrow-left pull-left fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="visible-lg arrow-right pull-right fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.left-arrow {
    right: 90%;
    left: 10%;
}
.right-arrow {
    left: 90%;
    right: 10%;
}
.arrow-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Could you build a jsfiddle or stacksnippet?

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Not a problem. Just give me a couple minutes.

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Do you mind just going to the website (http://thebenallen.net)

Comment: Just a side note: you claim to be a web-developer, still you use `<i>`as the container for the arrows? Really?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie the <i> tag is because he's using font-awesom that, as a web icon font, it's suggested to use with <i> tag. http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Comment: And, I quote the Fontawesome page: "You can place Font Awesome icons just about anywhere using the CSS Prefix fa and the icon's name. Font Awesome is designed to be used with inline elements (we like the <i> tag for brevity, but using a <span> is more semantically correct)." But then, I balk whenever I read both "for brevity" instead of "following standards" and see the word "bootstrap" included in any positive way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add to the `absolute` element this CSS because firefox need a explicit position when you use `position:absolute;`

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
```